# Rails 5 - Mongoid - Concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid

I'm trying to abstract generic functions to a model concern on a Rails 5 with Mongoid app. This is the first app I do with mongoid and with other projects I had no problems implementing the next:

movie.rb

```
class Movie
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Genericable

  field :name, type: String
  field :year, type: Date
  field :length, type: Integer
  field :writers, type: Array

  validates_presence_of :name, :year, :length
  validates_uniqueness_of :name

  index({name: 1}, {unique: true})

  has_many :writers, class_name: "Person"
  embeds_many :roles, class_name: "MovieRole"

end
```

genericable.rb (concern)

```
module Genericable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def self.s
    all.map{|x| x}
  end
end
```

(Methods are for demonstration purposes only).

When I try, on my rails console Movie.s I get next error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `s' for Movie:Class
```

Any clue about what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please see http://www.culttt.com/2015/07/08/working-with-mixins-in-ruby/

Comment: If you have only class methods in the mixin, then define methods without using `self.` and `extend Genericable` in your class.

Comment: It was this!. Thanks a lot.